# String not not accepted as keyof object?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that returns the key in a string, but I get error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof SavedMaterialValue'.(2322)

The related code and demo is:

```
interface SavedMaterialValue {
  flatCostPerUnit: number;
  numUnits: number;
}

function getName(type: number): keyof SavedMaterialValue {
  let name;
  if (type === 0)
    name = 'numUnits';
  else
    name = 'flatCostPerUnit'

  return name;
}
```

We can see this in the playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwG4QCYFk6RTBwA2AaqQK4oDeAUMsjCQQMID2AzmAArQCqIYGABcyEJQC2AI2gBuBuKmDhnMRJny6AXzp0YlEAjDB2IZAHMIYAHJxJEABRgAngAcI6qbKgBKMQDWEC7sMGiYOPiExORUtIok1uL2EAqMwGHO7igAvHnIAAy+iowgKcg5yADkGipgnFVpyBAknBAlyQ4V1cxsXLwCQmBVeoxQ1pRQ5mUOCtpAA

Anyone know how to allow this to pass?

Comment: `let name: keyof SavedMaterialValue`? Or just e.g. `return 'numUnits'`. Or you could `as const` both the strings.

Comment: Oh I learned about `as const` just now, thank you! Is there some good articles on `as const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a variable should generally be indicated *at the point where the variable is declared*. Type it as `keyof SavedMaterialValue` instead:

```
function getName(type: number): keyof SavedMaterialValue {
  let name: keyof SavedMaterialValue;
  if (type === 0)
    name = 'numUnits';
  else
    name = 'flatCostPerUnit'

  return name;
}
```

But the conditional operator would be easier here:

```
function getName(type: number): keyof SavedMaterialValue {
    return type === 0 ?  'numUnits' : 'flatCostPerUnit';
}
```

Another way to do it would be to use `as const` when assigning the strings, so they don't get widened to `string`:

```
function getName(type: number): keyof SavedMaterialValue {
  let name;
  if (type === 0)
    name = 'numUnits' as const;
  else
    name = 'flatCostPerUnit' as const

  return name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix my final code based on this example. https://imgur.com/a/l3Ra2Cb